# Why is django giving me an attribute error when I call _set.all() for its children models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models defined

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=144)

    @property
    def posts(self):
        self.Post_set.all()

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=144)
    text = models.TextField()
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog')
```

but the problem is, when I run shell, and enter

```
>>> blog = Blog(title="My blog")
>>> post = Post(title="My first post", text="Here is the main text for my blog post", blog=blog)
>>> blog.posts
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lucas/Programming/Python/Django/djangorestfun/blog/models.py", line 9, in posts
    self.Post_set.all()
AttributeError: 'Blog' object has no attribute 'Post_set'
>>>
```

Now I am having the following problem

```
>>> from blog.models import *
>>> blog = Blog(title="gewrhter")
>>> blog.save()
>>> blog.__dict__
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x259be10>, 'id': 1, 'title': 'gewrhter'}
>>> blog._state.__dict__
{'adding': False, 'db': 'default'}
>>> post = Post(title="sdhxcvb", text="hdbfdgb", blog=blog)
>>> post.save()
>>> post.__dict__
{'blog_id': 1, 'title': 'sdhxcvb', 'text': 'hdbfdgb', '_blog_cache': <Blog: Blog object>, '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x259bed0>, 'id': 1}
>>> blog.posts
>>> print blog.posts
None
```

---

### Second update

So I followed your guide, but I am still getting nothing. In addition, blog.posts gives me an error.

```
>>> from blog.models import *
>>> blog = Blog(title="asdf")
>>> blog.save()
>>> post = Post(title="asdf", text="sdxcvb", blog=blog)
>>> post.save()
>>> blog.posts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Blog' object has no attribute 'posts'
>>> print blog.all_posts
None
```

Comment: you should do `blog.post_set.add(post)`

Comment: @karthikr That returns None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post_set` should be in lowercase:

```
self.post_set.all()
```

**UPDATE:**

So it turns out that you can indeed create a property on `Blog` called `posts` and have it return a list of a blog's posts:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=144)

    @property
    def posts(self):
        return self.post_set.all() # note the `return`
```

`blog.posts` is now effectively an alias for `blog.post_set.all()`. Accordingly, the following lookups will now work:

```
from main.models import *

blog = Blog(title="asdf")
blog.save()

post = Post(title="asdf", text="sdxcvb", blog=blog)
post.save()

blog.posts # returns [<Post: Post object>]

blog.post_set.all() # returns [<Post: Post object>]
```

Finally, to get a list of dictionary values for each object, you can operate on `blog.posts` in the following manner:

```
list = []
for post in blog.posts:
    list.append(post.__dict__)

list # returns [{'text': u'sdxcvb', 'blog_id': 7L, '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x10a93c2d0>, 'id': 7L, 'title': u'asdf'}]
```

Comment: That fixes the Attribute error, but now it is returning nothing.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a minor change (needed to `return` `self.post_set.all()` in the `all_posts` property). I can now confirm that this works.

Comment: So final question, how can I get a list of dict values for each object in blog.all_posts?

Comment: Okay, I made a major update/revision to my answer. It should satisfy all your questions in one fell swoop. See above.

Answer (score 0):

or better, use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=144)
    text = models.TextField()
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog', related_name="posts")
```

And yuo can do that:

```
from main.models import *

post = Post(title="asdf", text="sdxcvb", blog=blog)
post.posts.create("asdf") #Create it "inline"

blog = Blog(title="another_asdf")
post.posts.add(blog) #Added it (don't need call save method!)

blog.posts.all() # returns [<Post: Post object>]
```

And then do use [value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) method

```
blog.posts.values() 
# [{'id': 1, 'tile': 'asdf', 'text': 'sdxcvb', 'blog': 'THE_BLOG_ID'}]
```

Hope helps!